# What will happen to QR Codes generated by Google Chart Tools: Infographics after it is fully deprecated?

Tags: google-visualization, qr-code

[The Google Chart Tools: Inforgraphics](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/) has been deprecated and will not longer be supported after 2015.  What will happen to QR Codes that have been generated by Google Chart Tools after it is no longer supported?  I know that the URL (`https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?`) will no longer return a generated QR Code. But what about QR Codes that were generated to go to a URL and then the QR image file was saved? Will those QR Codes still go to the URL if scanned after the full deprecation of Google Chart Tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QR Codes themselves can still be scanned and processed as happens now.  If you saved the generated image, it is a static file that is encoded with your data.  They will still decode... nothing will change.

Comment: Ok good.  I was wondering if the QR Code first linked you to a Google page and then to yours, like this blog warns about free QR generators: [link]http://notixtech.com/blog/why-you-should-think-twice-about-free-qr-code-generators

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but when you encode your URL in QR Code format, there's no need for a link shortener like goo.gl or TinyURL.  A QR Code can contain a very long URL without a problem as it scales in size accordingly.

Comment: The Google server definitely doesn't monkey around with your link and wrap it in a redirector.